# Gap between ng-repeat elements in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am having a problem with multiple `ng-repeat` elements when showing `div` elements as `inline-block`. There is a strange gap between elements where one `ng-repeat` ends and the next one starts, as illustrated by the image:

[image: gap when using ng-repeat]

I have created a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/mDHcEEaVng5VJlBbf3z1) to demonstrate this behavior:

Why is this happening and how to remove the gap?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/cCpFl5gqHMVMhmRxMNBZ)

There is a hack to remove space between inline elements that appears at line-break.

```
<div class="red" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <div class="blue number" ng-repeat="number in array1 track by $index">{{number}}</div><!--
  --><div class="green number" ng-repeat="number in array2 track by $index">{{number}}</div><!--
  --><div class="teal number" ng-repeat="number in array3 track by $index">{{number}}</div>
</div>
```

You could read more about other hacks [here](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Comment: oh thank you so much... i thought i was going to have to trash the whole section because of a few pixels of gap.

Answer (score 4):

That is because of the way the `.number` class in your css is defined. If you change it so that it contains a `float: left`, you'll get rid of the extra gap.

```
.number {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
```

You can see my updated [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/LPeKfqwWaiU2xm7hJW45)

Answer (score 4):

I know it's quite weird, but the whitespaces (crlf, spaces...) between your inline block divs make the space.

If you remove them, the space goes off. ([plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dX55EAM6a7ri6r7paQGy?p=preview))

I couldn't find any reference for explanation but my guess is that since the characters are between inline blocks, it's interpreted as a space as if block elements were actually inline ones (e.g. spans).

```
  <body ng-app="testRepeat">
    <div class="red" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
      <div class="blue number" ng-repeat="number in array1 track by $index">{{number}}</div><div class="green number" ng-repeat="number in array2 track by $index">{{number}}</div><div class="teal number" ng-repeat="number in array3 track by $index">{{number}}</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the whitespace between the `<div>` elements.  There are various ways to address this like the other answers have suggested.  My preferred layout is:

```
  <div class="blue number" ng-repeat="number in array1 track by $index">{{number}}</div
  ><div class="green number" ng-repeat="number in array2 track by $index">{{number}}</div
  ><div class="teal number" ng-repeat="number in array3 track by $index">{{number}}</div>
```

But the other suggestions are valid.

Another way to handle this without worrying about the HTML is to set the font size of the container to 0 so that the white space doesn't appear.

http://plnkr.co/edit/wXKl61lyiqdONbChYI9o?p=preview

The downside to this approach is that you can't use percentage sizes for the contained element fonts and you have to set them explicitly.