# Creating HTML elements with JavaScript vs regular HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an HTML code like this:

```
<div id="user-nav">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Subscribe Now</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Log In</button>
</div>
```

And then I tried to create the same thing with JavaScript:

```
// usernav - subscribe, login, settings
var subbtn = document.createElement("button");
subbtn.className = "btn btn-primary btn-sm";
subbtn.textContent = "Subscribe Now";
usernav.appendChild(subbtn);

var loginbtn = document.createElement("button");
loginbtn.className = "btn btn-primary btn-sm";
loginbtn.textContent = "Log In";
usernav.appendChild(loginbtn);
```

My JavaScript code works perfectly fine.

However, there is a minor difference in that, the buttons produced by JavaScript are touching each other, whereas when I just coded in HTML, there is a small gap between the two buttons.

When I inspect the element of two pages, the code is the same.

Why does this happen, and how can I produce the exact same result on JavaScript?

Comment: Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4u7cat0v/). It will help you in understanding better.

Comment: HTML contains white-space, which makes gap between inline elements, please see more in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083659/gap-between-ng-repeat-elements-in-angular/24083746#24083746

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why this Happens:

Your HTML contains white-space characters between the two elements, which gets collapsed into a single space with default styling.

However, your JavaScript does not create this white-space text-node.

## Proof:

Here's a snippet which shows there are actually 5 child nodes created by the HTML, 3 of which at text nodes from the white-space.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('user-nav');

console.log(el.childNodes);

document.getElementById('output').textContent = 'Number of Child nodes: ' + el.childNodes.length;
```

```html
<div id="user-nav">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Subscribe Now</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Log In</button>
</div>

<pre id="output"></pre>
```

If you check your console, you will see output like the following:

```
NodeList [ #text "
    ", <button.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm>, #text "
    ", <button.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm>, #text "
" ]
```

## Recreate the Result:

You can create a text node in JavaScript using `document.createTextNode` like this:

```js
var usernav = document.getElementById('user-nav');

var subbtn = document.createElement("button");
subbtn.className = "btn btn-primary btn-sm";
subbtn.textContent = "Subscribe Now";
usernav.appendChild(subbtn);

// Insert text node between the buttons:
usernav.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));

var loginbtn = document.createElement("button");
loginbtn.className = "btn btn-primary btn-sm";
loginbtn.textContent = "Log In";
usernav.appendChild(loginbtn);
```

```html
<div id="user-nav"></div>
```

However, you may want to consider using CSS instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the whitespace with a `textNode`:

```js
var usernav = document.getElementById('user-nav');
var subbtn = document.createElement("button");
subbtn.className = "btn btn-primary btn-sm";
subbtn.textContent = "Subscribe Now";
usernav.appendChild(subbtn);
usernav.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\n'));

var loginbtn = document.createElement("button");
loginbtn.className = "btn btn-primary btn-sm";
loginbtn.textContent = "Log In";
usernav.appendChild(loginbtn);
```

```html
<div id="user-nav">

</div>
```